# Typescript does not seem to restrict the parameters passed in a constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

While going through a tutorial by the youtube channel: The Net Ninja
In the 16th video of that playlist [youtube-link](https://youtu.be/XPGFqx8Vg-Y)
There was an interface created and that interface was

```
export interface HasFormatter {
  format(): string;
}
```

and then a  class was created with Type HasFormatter[the above interface]

```
export class Invoice implements HasFormatter {
  constructor(
    readonly client: string, 
    private details: string, 
    public amount: number,
  ){}

  format() {
    return `${this.client} owes £${this.amount} for ${this.details}`;
  }
}
```

and then an object of that class was created

```
let docOne: HasFormatter;
docOne = new Invoice('yoshi', 'web work', 250);
```

**My question** is how does TypeScript justify class Invoice implementing Type HasFormatter even though the constructor of that class has three parameters client,detail and amount

according to me the interface for that class should have been

```
export interface HasFormatter {
  client: string;
  details: string;
  amount: string;
  format(): string;
}
```

I tried running the code provided above and Typescript did not throw any error but i expected the code to show error as the class is taking 3 parameters as input which are even provided in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

`class Invoice implements HasFormatter` says `Invoice` has to have all properties `HasFormatter` declares (`format(): string` in this case), not the other way.

So `Invoice` can have any other properties as long as it has `format(): string`.

Comment: [codeSnippet](https://goonlinetools.com/snapshot/code/#gpni52t2waur2y1oe15ova) in this , if i try to create a new variable then typescript throws an error why is that so.

Comment: It's because it's an object *literal*. When you declare `me: IsPerson`, no one can access properties other than the properties declared in `IsPerson` (without casting to `any` or `unknown`). It's called Excess Property Checks.